# orientdb cluster names were ok in v2.0 but are now invalid?

Tags: orientdb

We recently upgraded from v2.0 to v2.1.9, and we're suddenly unable to query our clusters.  This query:

```
 select * from cluster:tdv-st-2014-01-19
```

worked fine in 2.0 (and earlier), but now we get (in console and in Java API):

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: Error parsing query: 
select * from cluster:tdv-st-2014-01-19
Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 26.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    <WHERE> ...
    <ORDER> ...
    <GROUP> ...
    <LIMIT> ...
    <SKIP2> ...
    <OFFSET> ...
    <TIMEOUT> ...
    <FETCHPLAN> ...
    <LOCK> ...
    <LET> ...
    <NOCACHE> ...
    <PARALLEL> ...
    <UNWIND> ...
    ";" ...
    <LET> ...
    <WHERE> ...
    <GROUP> ...
    <ORDER> ...
    <UNWIND> ...
    <SKIP2> ...
    <OFFSET> ...
    <LIMIT> ...
    <FETCHPLAN> ...
    <TIMEOUT> ...
    <LOCK> ...
    <PARALLEL> ...
    <NOCACHE> ...
```

Looks like it doesn't like "-" characters in the cluster name any more?  We've tried quoting the cluster name, etc. but haven't found a way to get this query to work. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Note: I'm able to create clusters with "-" characters without any problems, it's only when I try to query them that I get errors.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same issue, I think it's probably a bug

Comment: As a workaround you can select from cluster using its ID.
    
select from cluster:12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version 2.1.x has been implemented a new 'Strict SQL parser' which brings the following new features:

***) - as a valid character for identifiers (property and class names): in the old implementation you could define a property name like "simple-name" and do simple-SELECT name FROM Foo. This is not allowed anymore, Because - character is used for arithmetic operations (subtract). To use names with - character, use backticks. Example: SELECT `simple-name` FROM Foo

So the '-' is not a valid character for an identifier (to avoid clashes with subtraction)
see [link](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Release-2.1.0.html)

If you want,  you can disable the new parsing setting strictSql=false (see Studio -> db  tab)

Comment: So I guess it's a bug that I can create clusters with invalid characters without changing that setting?

Comment: I think yes, however it has been reported as future fix.

Answer (score 1):

How did you quote it? Have you already tried with backtik?

```
select * from `cluster:tdv-st-2014-01-19`
```

Comment: I had tried "select * from cluster:`tdv-st-2014-01-19`" which didn't work, but it appears that your suggestion does work.